# Fluent API One to Many mapping table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

It's really helpful if anyone could explain me how to create a mapping (associated)table for one to many relationship using Fluent API.`

```
    public class Category
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Image> Images { get; set; } 
}

public class Image
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Category> Category{ get; set; }
```

The mapping table should contain CategoryID and ImageID.
The solution should be something similar to this. (This is for many to many)

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Images).WithMany(i => i.Categories)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("CategoryID")
                .MapRightKey("ImageID")
                .ToTable("CategoryImage"));
```

I want Fluent API to create new mapping table for the below relationship.

```
 public class Category
{
public List<Image> Images{get; set;}
}

public class Image
{

public Category Category{ get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding NewTable:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<NewTable>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Category)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(_ => _.CategoryId);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<Image>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.NewTable)
    .WithMany(_ => _.Images)
    .HasForeignKey(_ => _.NewTableId)

public class NewTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
}

public class Image
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public int NewTableId { get; set; } 
    public virtual NewTable NewTable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response.Actually what I want is a new table with one category id with many Image Ids.

Comment: Your solution is working but I'm getting a circular referential integrity constraints error. So , I decided to remove  the OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention and I'm going to update the mapping table manually. Anyway thank you very much for your help.