# Entity Framework: One to many relationship using fluent API

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

I have two models (ApplicationStore, StoreAction) as shown below. 
I am trying to make one to many relationships i.e. ApplicationStore can have many StoreActions. 
I am using below fluent API syntax to make one to many relationship but getting error

> "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   StoreActions_Store_Target_StoreActions_Store_Source: : The number of
>   properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship
>   constraint must be identical."

```
public class ApplicationStore
{
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StoreAction> Actions { get; set; }
 }
 public class StoreAction
 {
        public int ActionId { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ActionRoute { get; set; }
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationStore Store { get; set; }
 }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationStore>().HasKey(m => new { m.StoreId, m.Name });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationStore>().Property(t => t.StoreId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationStore>().Property(m => m.Name).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StoreAction>().HasKey(m => new { m.ActionId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<StoreAction>().Property(m => m.ActionId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // configures one-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationStore>().HasMany(a => a.Actions).WithRequired(s => s.Store).HasForeignKey(s=> s.StoreId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Note: I have applied solution mentioned in following links
[Fluent API One to Many mapping table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185539/fluent-api-one-to-many-mapping-table)
[Entity Framework Relationship Fluent Api(One To Many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616314/entity-framework-relationship-fluent-apione-to-many)
and many others.